# Search pdf files in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there any way include pdf files in common drupal search. I tried http://drupal.org/project/search_files module. But it gives the results under a separate tab. Is there any to include them in common drupal search.

Comment: You're not alone on this: http://drupal.org/node/368195

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using hook_search you can include the files as well. Follow the code in search_files module and instead of displaying on a separate tab, you can combine them with other results!